# java script regular expression is not working in c#

Tags: c#, validation, whitespace

For me following reg is not working in c# mvc core 2.0, I want a `RegularExpression` to validate at least one or more charters required.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+)|(\]^)$
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what u are looking for:

```
^([ ]*+[0-9A-Za-z]++[ ]*+)+$
```